# In react, how to get value stored in draft.js to show up in another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I am new to react and having hard time figuring on how to show up the value from another component to the edit file component. Basically, I am able to create a message using draft.js rich text editor and able to save it to the database in the backend. Now I need to work on the update/edit part. How do I get the description state value to show up in the rich text editor? Can anyone please help?

**Create File**

```
import { EditorState } from 'draft-js'; 
class CreateModal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      description: EditorState.createEmpty()
    };
    this.handleEditorState = this.handleEditorState.bind(this);
  }

  handleEditorState(editorState) {
    this.setState({
      description: editorState
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { release } = this.props.state;
    return (
        <div>
          ...
            <CreateForm
              description={this.state.description}
              handleEditorState={this.handleEditorState}
              handleSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}
            />
          ...
      );
  }
}
```

**Form file**

```
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';
import '../../react-draft-wysiwyg.css';

class CreateForm extends Component {
  render() {
    const { description, handleEditorState, handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <form className="form-horizontal" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

        <Editor
          editorState={description}
          onEditorStateChange={handleEditorState}
        />

        {/* Buttons */}
        <div className={`modal-footer ${styles.modalFooter}`}>
          ...
        </div>
      </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Edit file**

```
class EditAccessInstructionModal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          description: EditorState.createEmpty()
      }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
      this.setState({
          description: this.props.accessInstructions.description
      });
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      this.setState({
          description: nextProps.accessInstructions.description
      });
  }

    onDescriptionChange(event)      {  this.setState({ description: event.target.value });    }

  render() {
      const { description } = this.state;
      return (
          <div className="btn-group">
              <div className={`modal-body ${styles['proj-modal-body']}`}>
                  <form id="modalForm" className="form-horizontal">

                      <Editor
                        value={description}
                      />

                  </form>
              </div>
          </div>
      )
  }
}
```

Comment: If you make a CodeSandbox I'll fix this for you.

Comment: @Colin is this good enough? https://codesandbox.io/s/82n058qnr8

Comment: I am not able to create a working example, but I am trying. If I get it to work I'll share new link.

Comment: Where does the <Editor> state live? That is, when you type in the WYSIWYG, where does the state update? Tried to find it in the sandbox but I'm not able to.

Answer (score 0):

`target.value` won't work. You shout use instead `getCurrentContent()`

Comment: Hey, could you put this solution in context based on OPs code?